# Is there way to solve authentication like the known programs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, authentication, debian

I have a program in Python. I would like when the program starts for it to ask me to enter root password, in a GUI dialog. I run the program then it shows the below error:

```
couldn't connect to display ": 0.0"
```

If I delete all lines with `pkexec` stuff inside `upgrade.py` then it works perfectly. Also if I run in `gnome-terminal` with the command  `sudo python3 /home/user/Python/upgrade.py` then it works too. Maybe it's a problem with `sudo`? Exactly the same happens with GTK for Python.

Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import subprocess
import sys

euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print ("Script not started as root. Running sudo..")
    args = ['pkexec', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('pkexec', *args)

print ('Running. Your euid is', euid)


root = Tk()
root.title('Update system')
#root.geometry("290x100")

def button_add1():
    callProcess = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-la'], shell=True)
    subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'ls', '-la'], check=True)

def button_add4():
    root.destroy()

# Define Buttons

button_1 = Button(root, text="Upgrade system",  padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add1)
button_4 = Button(root, text="Quit", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add4)

# Put the buttons on the screen

button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_4.grid(row=0, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Please I don't want like something this... [Simplest method of asking user for password using graphical dialog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724658/simplest-method-of-asking-user-for-password-using-graphical-dialog-in-python)

I would like authentication like programs such as `Synaptic`, `Gparted`, `Bleachbit`

I have [already asked on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177661/is-there-way-to-solve-authentication-like-the-known-programs?noredirect=1) but they said, It is related on system policy configuration and nothing related to Python or tkinter. This question is now migrated back to Stack Overflow!

I tried my code on Debian and Linux Mint.

Comment: You absolutely should not be running your GUI as `root`. The way Synaptic et al. do this is by spawning *a nongraphical component* by way of `pkexec`.

Comment: @tripleee Did you underastand my quesion? I have posted in stacoverflow. They said that "It is related on system policy configuration and nothing related to Python or tkinter" So I don't understand your answear. How do other programs in python ask for root password ? I want the same.

Comment: Did *you* not understand what *I* wrote? They use `pkexec` all right, but you can't run your whole GUI script under `pkexec` because it won't get access to the invoking user's `$DISPLAY`. Its manual page even mentions this specifically.

Comment: Maybe read this for background: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_GUI_applications_as_root

Comment: @tripleee Ok, I understand. Synaptic manager how to do it, or other programs? Would you like to help me how to do it like synaptic manager? My program just run 2 line code.

Comment: I don't know `tkinter` well enough to present a full answer, but basically only use `pkexec` when you run the subprocesses. Replace `os.system("what ever")` with `subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'what', 'ever'], check=True)` (the switch away from `os.system()` is not crucial but [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)).

Comment: @tripleee It doesn't work. I did ALL that you said. Look at my python code, I changed it. It show the same error. `line 17, in <module>    root = Tk()     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

Comment: You are still trying to run the GUI as `root`. You need to take out all the `euid` garbage. (Also, why do you run `subprocess` twice? You want to prefer `subprocess.run()` over `subprocess.Popen()` whenever you can. Also, `shell=True` is wrong when you pass in a list as the first argument. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538 which has a section about why.)

Comment: @tripleee   You didn't understand me. As I said I want `the same  other programs' . I want the program starts and press root password ONCE in the beggining.  How did it make other programs????? I  want the same. Thank you for helping but you below example I have to  press the button every time I.

Comment: Your updated example only runs `pkexec` once. (Repeatedly changing your code is somewhat problematic, as you are basically moving the goal posts.) If you want to run multiple commands behind one `pkexec`, you will need a shell after all; `subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'sh', '-c', 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y'], check=True)`

Comment: @tripleee I would like to change this `os.system("gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c \"sudo iptables -vnL; echo ''; read -p 'Press any key to exit'; exit; exec bash\"") ` with new `subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'sh', '-c',........blah` I would like to show gnome-terminal, without os.system.

Comment: So something like `subprocess.run(['gnome-terminal', '--', 'pkexec', 'sh', '-c', 'iptables -vnL; echo; read -p "Press any key"'])` would do that without attempting to run the terminal as root. Even better if you can push the `pkexec` further down into the command, like `... 'sh', '-c', 'pkexec iptables -vnL; ...'`

Comment: @tripleee I used your example but It doesn't work. There is no show any error.....Actually I want change os.system with new subprocess.run!!

Comment: Probably (accept the answer to your original question here, and) post a new question with clear requirements. I'm not in a place where I can access an Ubuntu GUI until maybe next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't try to run the GUI as `root`.  You should isolate the smallest possible component and only run that as privileged.  See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_GUI_applications_as_root and the note in the `pkexec` manual page which specifically explains that it will not allow you to take over the invoking user's `$DISPLAY`.

Here's a rough sketch, but it's untested right now.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# ^ this needs to be the absolutely first line of the file

from tkinter import *   # FIXME: probably avoid import *
# import os   # no longer used
import subprocess
# import sys  # no longer used

print ('Running. Your euid is whatever it is.')


root = Tk()
root.title('Update system')
#root.geometry("290x100")

def button_add1():
    subprocess.run(['ls', '-la'], check=True)
    subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'ls', '-la'], check=True)

def button_add4():
    root.destroy()

# Define Buttons

button_1 = Button(root, text="Upgrade system",  padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add1)
button_4 = Button(root, text="Quit", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add4)

# Put the buttons on the screen

button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_4.grid(row=0, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

If (as in your code before your edit) you want to run multiple commands behind one `pkexec`, you can do that with something like

```py
    subprocess.run(
        ['pkexec', 'sh', '-c', 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y'],
        check=True)
```

As an aside, if your example code is representative, you can replace `from tkinter import *` with `from tkinter import Tk` to avoid the `import *` antipattern.

Comment: I read your post. I don't care for security hole. I want run my program like the other. How to do that? I don't care for security hole. I was clear with that. Thank you!

Comment: You said you want to do it like Synaptic, `gparted`, etc. This is how they do it. As outlined on the Arch page, there is no simple way in Wayland to give `root` access to your `DISPLAY` session, though you could do it with an `xhost` hack to punch a hole large enough to sail the Starship Enterprise through.

Comment: It is not the same.  1. I want before start the program ask me for password. 2. Your example It is not the same like I said. It start the program then push button ,then write password then run bash command and finish. `If push button second time` you have to enter password again. I want enter a password ONCE in the beggining. May I have your e-mail or personal mesage? Thank you very much.

Comment: Update your question to clearly state your requirements. No, I don't engage in off-site interactions, but you can find me in chat if you like (though you need 30 rep for that to work).

Comment: It doesn't work with `from tkinter import Tk` only with `from tkinter import *`

Comment: I guess maybe you need to import `Button` too.

Comment: Please Can you tell why is better `from tkinter import Tk` from 
`from tkinter import * `

Comment: @user14770539:  the preferred way to import tkinter is `import tkinter as tk`, and then prepend `tk.` to all tkinter classes (eg: `root = tk.Tk()`). Wildcard imports are discouraged by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). In short, wildcard imports pollute the namespace.